# Issue with options in ICME file uploader missing

Tags: files

I'm using Drupal 8 and I added IMCE so that we could upload files. But, some things seem to be missing. First I can only upload images now, there's not option to search the website directories which means that if I have a icon I use in many places I have to upload it each time. You can search the website directories when you link to files though.

Secondly there are no link options like choosing targets like _blank. Is this the way the module works or is something conflicting with it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. This is a big headache.
We want to make all off-site (external) links have target = _blank.

Solution: The CKeditor Anchor Link module, anchor_link, adds the other link properties (as it existed in Drupal 7). You have to edit the text formats and include the new buttons that anchor_link creates. However, these buttons are identical to the ones created by the Link module (in core D8), so make sure to remove them and drag the new ones (from anchor_link) in.

Comment: Solution: The CKeditor Anchor Link module, anchor_link, adds the other link properties (as it existed in Drupal 7). You have to edit the text formats and include the new buttons that anchor_link creates. However, these buttons are identical to the ones created by the Link module (in core D8), so make sure to remove them and drag the new ones (from anchor_link) in.